# Mocking a singleton that does not return the instance in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, singleton

So, I have a class I need to mock, since I don't want the tests to actually do this connection, I want to provide fake results for the `privateMethodCall()`:

```java
public final Connection {
  private Connection() {
    //does some stuff  
  }

  public static void get(/*some params*/) {
    Connection conn = new Connection();
    con.privateMethodCall();
  }
}
```

The issue is most singletons I see mocked are returning the instance in the public static method, this one is not.

In the class I'm testing, the Connection class is just called in a private method from the method I'm trying to test (`prepareForThing()`).

```java
import Connection;

public class ManagerClass {
  ManagerClass(/* some params*/){
    //Does some stuff
  }

  void prepareForThing(/* params */) {
    // Does stuff
    doThing();
  }

  private void doThing(/* more params */) {
    // Does some stuff
    Connection.get();
    // Continues doing stuff
  }
}
```

Even if I create another constructor and pass the mock class like is suggested [Using Singleton with Interfaces Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074628/using-singleton-with-interfaces-java), since the instance is just created and used within the static method it wouldn't work.

My workaround so far is to pass a boolean `isTest` to the class I'm testing, and then modify the `Connection` class so it can be extended, write a `ConnectionMock`, and if the `isTest` is set to true, modify the call. But this makes the `ManagerClass` depend on a test class, `ConnectionMock`, which is not good

But I don't know if there might be a better workaround with mockito or something. I would like the mock to be available for other tests, rather than create it for the test only. And I'm not sure extending this class is the best approach, but I can't create an interface because all methods in `Connection` are private or static. Any ideas?

Comment: You have two options here: either you use PowerMockito (cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585323/how-do-i-mock-a-static-method-that-returns-void-with-powermock) and leave the code as-is, or you take a Runnable in construction parameter of your class and then in production you inject the runnable as `() -> Connection.get()` whereas in the tests you simply inject an empty runnable `() -> {}`. I'd go for PowerMockito (it keeps the production code cleaner) unless you're forbidden to add the dependency, in that case the runnable is your only option

Comment: That's one of the reasons why singletons and static methods are generally discouraged. One possible solution: create a wrapper around your singleton, inject the wrapper and then replace the wrapper with a test impl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to hide your singleton. Singletons are inherently hard to test, because you only have a single instance and a single implementation. All clients of static methods are *tightly coupled* to them.

Note that your Singleton isn't a real singleton in the classical sense, because multiple instance of it exist.

Wrap your singleton and inject the wrapper to your clients to hide it.

```
public final ConnectionSingleton {
  private ConnectionSingleton() {
    //does some stuff  
  }

  public static void get(/*some params*/) {
    ConnectionSingleton conn = new ConnectionSingleton();
    con.privateMethodCall();
  }
}

public interface Connection {
  void get();
}

public class ProductionConnection implements Connection {
  @Override
  public void get() {
    Connection.get(); // production implementation delegates to singleton
  }
}
```

```
import Connection;

public class ManagerClass {
  private final Connection connection; // depend on the interface
  ManagerClass(Connection connection){
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  void prepareForThing(/* params */) {
    // Does stuff
    doThing();
  }

  private void doThing(/* more params */) {
    // Does some stuff
    connection.get(); // call the instance method of the interface
    // Continues doing stuff
  }
}
```

In your production code instantiate your manager as `new ManagerClass(new ProductionConnection())`. In your test, inject a mock or a custom dummy implementation:

```
class TestConnection implements Connection {
  @Override public void get() { /* do nothing */ }
}

@Test
void myTest() {
  ManagerClass manager = new ManagerClass(new TestConnection());
  manager.prepareForThing();
}
```

Since this interface only has a single method, you could pass an empty statement lambda too: `new ManagerClass(() -> {})`.

You might find other solutions for the underlying problem (which is using `new` in your methods) in the related, but not quite duplicated, question [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test)